# Cannot find the output of XMLTestRunner

Tags: python, jenkins

I'm using a unittest to xml library so I can see my test results from python in Jenkins.

I don't know how to configure the Unit testresult plugin the right way.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(testRunner=xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(output='test-reports'))
```

I can't find the output (test-reports) anywhere in my directory, i've searched my whole ubuntu system but cannot seem to find it. The tests are running

Answer (score 0):

Two things to try:

- use an *absolute path to the directory*
- set the `buffer` to `False`:

  ```
  unittest.main(testRunner=xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(output='/absolute/path/to/test-reports', 
                                                   buffer=False))
  ```

Comment: This doesn't help me.

Comment: For me it is working.. But I am not clear, why it is not take relative path.